# How to Insert JSON data to BYTEA column in the table in POSTGRESQL?

Tags: postgresql, json

So, I came across the function script which is converting JSON data to BYTEA and then insert as a record in the table in a BYTEA column. (As I assumed what the code is doing)

In Oracle the function utl_raw.cast_to_raw converts the data to blob data and records the data in the table in Blob column. Giving the following output message, "anonymous block completed"

The following is the code,

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION INS_BLOB() RETURNS VOID AS $$
DECLARE
    v1 "TBL1"."COL1"%TYPE;
    v2 "TBL1"."COL2"%TYPE;
BEGIN
v1 := utl_raw.cast_to_raw('{
 "APPLICATION": {
   "MEMORY": {
   "OPTIONS" :{
                "SOMETHING" : "SOMETHING",
                "format" : "SOMETHING",
                "System" : "",
                "IP" : "",
                "Port" : "",
                "template" : "",
                "Path" : "" ,
                "Name" : "QUEUE",
                "URL" : ""              
     }');

 v2 := utl_raw.cast_to_raw('{
    "APPLICATION": {
   "MEMORY": {
   "OPTIONS" :{
                "SOMETHING" : "SOMETHING",
                "format" : "SOMETHING",
                "System" : "",
                "IP" : "",
                "Port" : "",
                "template" : "",
                "Path" : "" ,
                "Name" : "QUEUE",
                "URL" : ""  
                    }');

 INSERT INTO "TBL1" ("SN","COL1","COL2") values(1,v1, v2);
END;
$$

LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
COMMIT;
```

**[SOLVED]** Edit:  So generally the problem was nothing. So all I had to remove was the **utl_raw.cast_to_raw** line and execute it as it is. No errors, no problems. THANKS

Comment: Unrelated, but: you should really avoid those dreaded quoted identifiers (`"COL1"` - they are much more trouble than they are worth it).

Comment: I agree, but I already made a leap on that one by making all of it case sensitive. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no reason to convert anything, just insert the JSON strings (after making them valid JSON):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION INS_BLOB() RETURNS VOID AS $$
BEGIN
 INSERT INTO "TBL1" ("SN","COL1","COL2") 
 values(1, 
    '{
      "APPLICATION": {
         "MEMORY": {
         "OPTIONS" :{
                      "SOMETHING" : "SOMETHING",
                      "format" : "SOMETHING",
                      "System" : "",
                      "IP" : "",
                      "Port" : "",
                      "template" : "",
                      "Path" : "" ,
                      "Name" : "QUEUE",
                      "URL" : ""              
        }}}}', --<< add the missing curly braces!
     '{
      "APPLICATION": {
       "MEMORY": {
       "OPTIONS" :{
                "SOMETHING" : "SOMETHING",
                "format" : "SOMETHING",
                "System" : "",
                "IP" : "",
                "Port" : "",
                "template" : "",
                "Path" : "" ,
                "Name" : "QUEUE",
                "URL" : ""  
        }}}}'); --<< add the missing curly braces!
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
COMMIT;
```

---

You also don't need PL/pgSQL for this. A `language sql` function would be enough (you would need to remove the `begin` and `end` though)

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason to ever do that. PostgreSQL has a binary JSON type, `jsonb`. Just store your data as JSONB.

```
CREATE TABLE foo (
    jsondata  jsonb
);

INSERT INTO foo (jsondata) VALUES ( $${"foo": "bar"}$$ );
```

This will give you a ton of operators and functions that will natively work with this type.
[*JSONB are varlena (just like bytea) under the hood anyway*](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/master/src/include/utils/jsonb.h#L77)

See also,

- [JSONB Functions and Operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html)

Comment: Hi, I would appreciate if the answer was inclined towards my code which I am struggling to debug.

Comment: @devilboy477 I have no idea what you're even trying to do. PostgreSQL doesn't have `utl_raw.cast_to_raw`. It has a cast from text to binary json. It's implicit (happens in my answer above).

Comment: But, Evan how should I enter those values one at a time, I need something which compiles it together (squeeze in as a single data record) and inserts in the table column. 
PS: I am super new to postgres

Comment: @devilboy477 I'm not sure what you mean when you say "one at a time" show us what you want you to do with SQL. And ignore everything about how you're currently *trying* to do it.

Comment: @devilboy477: you don't need to convert anything. Just insert the values.

Comment: Hi, I actually just inserted the values and it worked. But is there any way I can store it as a raw file in the records ?

Comment: @devilboy477: JSONB is a binary format (which compresses large values), why would you want anything else. What do you mean with "raw file in the record"? You are not using record variables there and I don't see any "files" either.

Comment: Hi, I have edited the question. And it seems I am required to convert it to BYTEA data type so I can store in one @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: I have no idea what you're doing or why you're doing it and you're not sufficiently communicating your intent nor your use case/environment

Comment: @devilboy477: there is no "requirement" to store a JSON values as `bytea`. You seem to suffer from ADOS (All Databases are Oracle Syndrome). Storing json in a `bytea` is utter nonsense. `jsonb` **is** already a binary storage and a much superior one for storing JSON values .

Comment: The thing which we are trying to address is the fetch speed. It is much easier to fetch a bytea data than a json data. I just want to know if this conversion can happen, if yes how? @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: @devilboy477: in which programming language is fetching a byte array and converting it into a properly encoded string easier than just fetching a string?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I clearly lack the knowledge to put up a debate. I have only known DB for a month now. I know it sucks to follow the requirements but cannot help it. it's BYTEA or nothing!

Comment: @devilboy477: no offense, but if you lack the knowledge, then why don't you accept the opinion of people that do have the knowledge. Using `bytea` for JSON values **is the wrong thing to do**. Period.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name you are taking this completely in the wrong direction. I completely agree with all of you here and it works too. But its necessary I follow the build of my application. The application is already happy and running on Oracle and I really want to move it to PostgreSQL. I will still stick to my question Can I convert json to bytea ?

Comment: @devilboy477: Sorry, but I am not going to help you implement a completely wrong approach that will be a nightmare to maintain and that will perform poorly.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I respect your ethics and shall ask no further.